# Hasura session variable as parameter in posgtgress function

Tags: postgresql, hasura

In hasura you can use column presets to automatically populate table column with value from the jwt token. However I have a scenario where I don't want to directly write the session into the column but instead pass it down as a parameter of a custom postgress function I wrote which returns the correct value that should be used by default.

But I have no idea how to pass hasura session variable as the function parameter, or if even hasura supports that.

So how do I pass say 'x-hasura-user-id' as parameter of get_value() custom function?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for friend? https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#allow-access-to-session-variables-by-computed-fields-fix-3846

Comment: That is only for computed fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You can pass it as an argument in your function.

Lets say you have get_value(`...some vars` , `hasura_session json`) and all you have to do is either alter your `.yaml` config for the fucntion and add the `hasura_session` or use the the Hasura UI and add it trough that.

[image]